# Where to get Hardware info about Routers

Tags: router, hardware

I have been trying to get information about the hardware itself from Cisco routers but I was unable to find that on Google. It seems weird I cant find that info neither on Cisco page itself.

My question is, can someone direct me to a page where I can get the CPU, the amount of memory and the overall hardware features of an enterprise Cisco router?

Thanks!

Comment: What router you want this for? And do you already own the router?

Comment: no. I dont plan on buying it. I want to know why its so difficult to get information about this and possible to get a link to a model and its corresponding hardware features.

Comment: Went to ebay https://www.ebay.com/itm/Cisco-3845-Integrated-Services-Router/192550174377?hash=item2cd4e27ea9:g:iSoAAOSwkcFbB~qq and googled "Cisco 3845 Integrated Services Router hardware spec" and found https://www.cnet.com/products/cisco-3845-integrated-services-router-router-desktop-series/specs/ as an example. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Their is also a product data sheet here https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/3800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/product_data_sheet0900aecd8016a8e8.html and some interesting stuff here for that unit https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/routers/3800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/tsd-products-support-series-home.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: if you can't find detailed info from the vendor and no detailed review you'll have to take them apart yourself.

Apparently, most customers don't require or ask for detailed datasheets any more, so they've grown out of style...

Comment: There are a few reasons for this. One big one being that many vendors don't want customers to choose their product based solely on how much hardware gets stuffed into it. Rather, more useful metrics like total request capacity, throughput, feature compatibility, etc are not only easier to sell in many cases but are easier for people to right-size within their infrastructure.

Comment: One side of the medal - additionally, customers being able to compare technical details means less brand adherence. But seriously, it's less and less about what the hardware can do and more and more about what the software can do.